# Is border-radius of 1px more performant than border-radius of 10px?

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome-devtools, css

Basically I'm wondering if the rendering performance difference that Microsoft, LinkedIn and others refer to is between 0px and 1px or between 1px to infinity px.

Comment: why the downvote? I don't know how to measure this. That is why I asked.

Comment: No difference according to [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/RCgQV), in any browser...

Comment: @OneTrickPony thanks! yeah it looks like the big difference is between setting `border-radius` and not: [http://jsfiddle.net/RCgQV/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/RCgQV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/), it stops short of answering your question about if there is any difference between higher and lower border-radius pixel values. But it does clearly describe how things were tested (which tools and methods were used), and it does provide some test pages which you could modify a little and use to test this yourself.